# How do i implement a non-consumable in-app purchase on an app with its own Login/Registration System?

Tags: swift, in-app-purchase

How do i implement a non-consumable in-app purchase on an app with its own Login/Registration System.(Users can signup, login and logout of the App). From Apple's perspective when a user purchases something non-consumable using IAP, he should be able to access the purchased content on all of his devices. then, it would be possible for a user to purchase the product and proceed to logout of the APP, log back in as a different 'app' user, hit restore transactions button (required if the app is using non-consumables) and get the product for free. How can i prevent this loophole?

Furthermore, App store rejected one of my build saying "We noticed that your app requires users to register with personal information to purchase non account-based in-app purchase products, which does not comply with the App Store Review Guidelines.

Apps cannot require user registration prior to allowing access to app content and features that are not associated specifically to the user".

I had redirected the user to login screen (if a user was not logged in to the app) before making the purchase, and this seems to be the issue of the rejection as apple says: "Apps cannot require user registration prior to allowing access to app content and features that are not associated specifically to the users."

as Login is necessary for authentication in my app, how do i get around the rejection and implement both IAP and Login.

All ideas are appreciated.

Comment: If you have our custom login, meaning your have your custom backend you need to validate transactions on your backend. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html

Comment: yes i have done the receipt validation on my backend and there are no issues with that. but apple rejects my app if i direct an user to login screen before making the purchase.

Comment: @Frankenxtein how have you solved this issue?
I'm having the same issue where I have my own login system and non-consumables are tied to the Apple ID not my custom users